# How to change the boot animation in Galaxy Tab 2 GT-P3100?

Tags: boot-animation, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I tried changing the boot animation in my Galaxy Tab 10.1  by this tutorial:

http://mobilecon.info/how-to-change-android-bootanimation.html

and it worked too but when I tried doing the same in Galaxy Tab 2 ICS it doesn't work the files are in different places..
Can anyone help me with a way to change the boot animation?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you're rooted and your ROM supports changing the boot animation, there are a number of apps in the Play Store.

Here's one - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.apps.boot.animations

Comment: thats fine but i wanna know what files are being changed while changing the boot animation in Tab-2. and thanks for the answer too.